# Geting an error while updating person accounts

Tags: person-accounts

> Visualforce Error Help for this Page
>
> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Error is in expression '{!Submit}' in component 
>   in page vfp_updateaddress_policyparty_peracc:
>   Class.UpdateAddress_PolicyParty_PerAcc.Submit: line 99, column 1
>
> Class.UpdateAddress_PolicyParty_PerAcc.Submit: line 99, column 1

Code snippet which is throwing error:

```
Public List<Account> AccUpdate{get;set;}
 List<Account> Acc_Uplst = [select id,PersonContactId from Account where PersonContactId = :PersnId]; 
 for(Account acc : Acc_Uplst){
                acc.Pending_Mailing_City__c = City;
                system.debug('>>>>city>>>'+acc.Pending_Mailing_City__c);
                acc.Pending_Mailing_State__c = State;
                acc.Pending_Mailing_Street__c = Street;
                acc.Pending_Mailing_Zip_Code__c = Decimal.ValueOf(PostalCode);
                AccUpdate.add(acc);
           }  

             if(!AccUpdate.isEmpty()){
                Update AccUpdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the error is `AccUpdate.add(acc);`, this would happen because you've not yet initialized that variable. Make sure you add this line before your for loop starts:

```
AccUpdate = new Account[0];
```